# using radix-sort on real numbers

Tags: sorting

given the fact that I have a list of numbers, and for each number n I know that n is presented by some constant number of bits.

Can I use radix-sort even if my numbers are Real Numbers and not necessarily Integers?

Answer (score 0):

You can just traverse all digits from the right of the floating point to negative by multiplying them by -1, also, every number you covert will keep a reference to the real number value, otherwise you need to covert the changed numbers back to the original values. The last operation can cost you O(wn) if coverting again, or just O(n) if keepinging a reference, if W is considered a constant, then it doesnt matter . Then, using radix sort without taking in account of the floating points.
Efficiency: O(wn) wheras w is the constant number of digita and n is the amount of numbers provided.
Radix sort works with the same efficienxy.
Total efficiency: O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming IEEE format and ignoring issues like NAN's, then cast the floats to integers or doubles to long long for the sort and toggle the sign bits on the most significant "digit". This is assuming a conventional counting / radix sort performed least significant "digit" first. A "digit" size of 8 bits is common.

You could also toggle the sign bits on the entire array before and after the sort, which is the same as Ori Rafeal's suggestion of multiply by -1.